# Anchor links in GatsbyJS + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now. I created a GatsbyJS project after I made my project in a normal create-react-app. Everything worked fine until I made some *big* changes to the code. This ruined my navigation - BUT NOT COMPLETELY! The logo navigation still works and the links in the footer, but not the NavBar items. I'm using the gatsby plugin: 'gatsby-plugin-anchor-links' (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-anchor-links/).

Here is my NavBarItem code (component):

```js
import React from "react"
import "../../Bulma.css"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

function NavBarItem(props) {
  return (
    <Link
      className={"pl-6 pr-6 has-text-black navbar-item " + props.class}
      to={"/#" + props.location}
    >
      {props.text}
    </Link>
  )
}

export default NavBarItem
```

Here is my NavBar component:

```js
import React from "react"
import NavBarItem from "./assets/NavBarItem"
import "../Bulma.css"
import "./NavBar.css"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import logo from "../../static/dronarfoton_logo.png"

class NavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isActive: true,
    }
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({ isActive: !this.state.isActive })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav
        className="navbar has-text-white has-background-grey-lighter has-navbar-fixed-top is-fixed-top"
        role="navigation"
        aria-label="main navigation"
      >
        <div className="navbar-brand">
          <a href="#Top" className="navbar-item">
            <img
              alt="Logga som det står DrönarFoton på. Det visar en drönare och text."
              src={logo}
              width="112"
              height="28"
            />
          </a>

          <a
            role="button"
            className={
              this.state.isActive
                ? "navbar-burger burger"
                : "is-active navbar-burger burger"
            }
            aria-label="menu"
            aria-expanded={this.state.isActive ? "false" : "true"}
            data-target="navbarBasicExample"
            onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div
          className={this.state.isActive ? "is-active navbar-menu" : "is-block"}
        >
          <div className="navbar-end">
            <NavBarItem location="Top" text="Hem" />
            <NavBarItem location="OmOss" text="Om oss" />
            <NavBarItem location="Kontakt" text="Kontakt" />
            <NavBarItem class="is-disabled" location="#" text="❌ Galleri ❌" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}

export default NavBar
```

Again, the 'navbar-brand' link WORKS but not the navbar items.

My thought was that it has something to do with how it's rendered, but I can't figure out how & why this is happening.

Another interesting part is that **THE LINKS WORK IF I DISABLE JAVASCRIPT IN MY BROWSER**

If someone has an idea of why this is happening. Please let me know.

Thanks //Gustav

Comment: Do you have any live site/CodeSandbox to check those links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `prop` `location` in your `<NavBarItem>` component but in the end, you are rendering a `<Link>`, that doesn't accept hashes (`#`) neither an anchor behavior. As you can see in [`<Link>`'s API documentation (in-app navigation)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/#recommendations-for-programmatic-in-app-navigation):

> Neither `<Link>` nor `navigate` can be used for in-route navigation with a
> hash or query parameter. If you need this behavior, you should either
> use an anchor tag or import the `@reach/router` package—which Gatsby
> already depends upon—to make use of its navigate function.

If you want to use an anchor link in your `<NavBarItem>`, you should use a regular `<a>` or using `gatsby-plugin-anchor-links` properly:

```
  <AnchorLink
    to="/about#team"
    title="Check out our team!"
    className="stripped"
    stripHash
  />
```

Keep in mind that using a regular `<a>`, you will lose all the benefits on the `@reach/routing` and you will refresh the page completetly.

Comment: For what it's worth, the documentation does a poor job of explaining the shortcoming with `Link` and `navigate`. Either can be used for linking to pages with a fragment in the URL just fine, but they do not include any behavior to scroll the browser to an element on the page identified by the anchor. That responsibility is yours, and can be easily had by exporting a `shouldUpdateScroll` function from `gatsby-browser.js` with the desired behavior.

Comment: <AnchorLink> not working for me, had to resort to using the <a> tag in order to get the anchor to work

Comment: The plugin may be deprecated, it will rely on your dependency version. As I suggest, if the plugin is not an option, you only valid way is using `<a>` or customizing the `Link` from `@reach/router` (not from Gatsby)

Comment: Actually the <a> tag isn't even working :(

Comment: Well, it should be as long it's HTML. Without seeing any implementation I'm not able to guess what could possibly be wrong. Feel free to reach out or open a new question.